# Django - Dynamic filter Foreign Key choices on previοus user choice

Tags: django, dynamic, foreign-keys, filtering

I'm building an app for personnel. Someone belongs in a company, which have different departments. A department from one company may have the same name with the department of another company.

The models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    COMPANIES = (('Comp1', 'Comp1'), ('Comp2', 'Comp2'), ('Comp3', 'Comp3'),)
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5, choices=COMPANIES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Personel(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The (very basic) form:

```
class PersonelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personel
        fields = ['name', 'company', 'department']
```

Companies and Departments are managed from the admin page.

The view:

```
def new_personel(request):
    template = 'TestApp/new_personel.html'
    form = PersonelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

With the current code, in the department select field are shown all the departments from all companies in the database. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user selects the company, the department select field dynamically being filled with the departments from the selected company.

All the solutions I managed to find requires the company being selected before the form loads (e.g. set company in a form and continue to another form for the rest fields, use of ModelChoiceField, use of limit_choices_to and define **init**).

Is there a way to achieve this through Django or with the use of JavaScript in the html?
(of course more than welcome a solution that can do that in the admin page also)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ModelSelect2 widget from [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/).
You would define a form

```
from dal import autocomplete

class PersonelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.all(),
                                 widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='department-autocomplete', forward=('company', )))
```

Then you need to define the `department-autocomplete` URL view

```
class DepartmentAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Department.objects
        company = self.forwarded.get('vzw')
        if company:
            queryset = queryset.filter(company__pk=company)
        return queryset.filter(name__icontains=self.q) if self.q else queryset
```

The `self.q` in this view is the query that you're typing in the form. Also don't forget to import the necessary javascript and css as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though this is an autocomplete box rather than a dropdown list. I found the solution here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html